# beforeSave is same on update action in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Why yii2 identify actionUpdate is same actionCreate.
Why I said like that :
This is the case

I have a lot of field such as `name, created_by` with a special field in db that I want to auto_increment (but not primary key).
the field is named `nomor_surat` (In english : letter_number)

So, if a new record that would be insert, `no_surat` will be 1,2,3,4, so on so on.
Then I decide to create action beforeSave() like this :

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
    parent::beforeSave($insert);

    $nomor = Request::find()->select('max(nomor_surat) as max')->scalar();
    $this->nomor_surat = $nomor + 1;

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

In actionCreate, its success.
Let say no_surat=1

But, f I update no_surat_1, let say I want to name in this record,
the no_suart is change=2

Please Advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$insert` variable is actually telling you if this is create or update action. This is boolean and it's `true` if model is being inserted and `false` if model is being updated.

And you use wrong logic in your example. It should be:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        if ($insert) { // only on insert
            $nomor = Request::find()->select('max(nomor_surat) as max')->scalar();
            $this->nomor_surat = $nomor + 1;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```